# Why do I lose all data when I use my POST Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a view where I have different functionalities. One of them is that I should be able to write comments. Iam able to write a comment, but the problem is when I have made a comment, my view loses all data about the object I am going to write a comment about.
An example, this is how my URL will be before `/Ticket/Info/36` and after `/Ticket/Info/0`.

**This is what my controller looks like where I make my comment.**

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Comments(CommentVM obj)
        {

   
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                
                _db.Commenents.Add(obj.Comment);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }

          

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Info), new { @id = obj.Ticket.Ticket_Id });

        }
```

**My info controller where i have my view**

```
public IActionResult Info(int id)
        {

            CommentVM t = new CommentVM 
            { 
                Comment = new Comments { Ticket_Id = id },


                UserTicketList = _db.UserTickets.Include(n => n.ApplicationUser).Include(n => n.Ticket)
                .Where(n => n.Ticket_Id == id).ToList(),

                UserTicket = new UserTicket()
                {
                    Ticket_Id = id
                },

                Ticket = _db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Ticket_Id == id)

            };

            t.Ticket = _db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Ticket_Id == id);
            if (t.Ticket == null)
            {
                t.Ticket = new Ticket();
            }
            t.Comments = _db.Commenents.Where(f => f.Ticket_Id == id);

            List<string> tempListOfAssignedUsers = t.UserTicketList.Select(n => n.UserId).ToList();
            //Not in LINQ clause
            var tempList = _db.ApplicationUser.Where(n => !tempListOfAssignedUsers.Contains(n.Id)).ToList();

            t.DevList = tempList.Select(i => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = i.Email,
                Value = i.Id.ToString()
            });

            //


            return View(t);

        }
```

As you can see, I have `return RedirectToAction(nameof(Info), new { @id = obj.Ticket.Ticket_Id });` I have also tested with slightly different variants such as `return RedirectToAction("Info", new { Id = obj.Ticket_Id });`  but I still get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted `return RedirectToAction("Info", new { Id = obj.Ticket_Id });` is not work in your case. I think it's because it's your passing `id` and parameter  `id` letter's uppercase difference.for that still you found unexpected result.

Try exact same code like below:-

```
return RedirectToAction("info", new { 
               id = obj.Ticket_Id,
           });
```

```
public ActionResult Info(int id)
{
    //clarify code
}
```

make sure your `obj.Ticket_Id,` has contained `id` and I assume that it is. it resolves your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! unfortunately it did not seem to work. I exchanged the code for the one you posted. However, I got the same result as before

Comment: @Daniel please debug your code and make sure you ```obj.Ticket_Id``` has contain id.  did you use another separate controller for your info method?

Comment: It seems that I do not get an ID. I tested a bit more and now get this error message ```System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'``` Both my comments and info are within the same controller

Comment: @Daniel where exactly you found this null exception?

Comment: After I have used my POST and it returns to Info :)

Comment: @Daniel please debug this code.and tell me exact the line where you found this null exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235486/discussion-between-pritom-sarkar-and-daniel).